# Pyspark, perform word count in an RDD comprised of arrays of strings.

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, word-frequency

I have a huge text file of wikipedia articles, each line of the file is one article. I am trying to create an RDD that will consist of arrays of strings, each array will represent a line of the text file (a complete article) then I want to count the word frequency of each array so at the end I will have:

[ [article1 words-frequency tuples] , [article2 words-frequency tuples], ... ]

I create the RDD:

```
corpus = sc.textFile("articles.txt")
```

Then I do a flat map to split in distinct arrays of Strings

```
docs = corpus.flatMap(lambda doc: [doc.split(' ')])
```

If I try to do a second Map in order to create word-value pairs ("word",1) this way:

```
docs.map(lambda word: (word,1))
```

I get an article-value pair, this would be helpful if I wanted to count the number of articles in the corpus, how can I count the words in each article?

I guess by referring to each array in the RDD and performing reduce on this specific array each time, I tried

```
docs.map(lambda word: (word[0],1)))
```

but this just gets the first string of each array. Any suggestions are more than welcome! many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to drop enclosing list from `flatMap`:

```
from operator import add

docs = corpus.flatMap(lambda doc: doc.split(' '))
docs.map(lambda word: (word,1)).reduceByKey(add)
```

You can also `flatMap` to pairs directly:

```
corpus.flatMap(lambda doc: [(x, 1) for x in doc.split(' ')]).reduceByKey(add)
```

or emit partial aggregates with `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter 

corpus.flatMap(lambda doc: Counter(doc.split(' ')).items()).reduceByKey(add)
```